# How to deselect NA and (blanks) from a pivot table

Tags: vba, excel

I have this code that deselects every value less than 10 and it works.

```
Dim pt as PivotTable
Dim pf as PivotField
Dim pi as PivotItem

Set pt = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1")
Set pf = pt.PivotFields("Count")

For each pi in pf.PivotItems
If pi.Value < 10 Then pi.Visible = False
Next
```

However I do have text strings in here (like "NA" and (blanks)) that is causing this formula to not work. i get an error message: "Run-time error '13': Type mismatch" when pi.Value encounters "NA". I adjusted the code to be:

```
If pi.Value < 10 or pi.Value ="NA" or pi.Value ="(Blank)" Then pi.Visible = False
```

However I am still getting the same error Message. us there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

This should make it work:

```
If IIf(VarType(Pi.Value) = vbError, 0, Pi.Value) < 10 Then Pi.Visible = False
```

If you really only want to eliminate `Blanks`, `Nulls`, and `Errors` then you can also use this:

```
For Each pi In pf.PivotItems
    If IIf(VarType(pi.Value) = vbError Or _
           VarType(pi.Value) = vbEmpty Or _
           VarType(pi.Value) = vbNull, _
           0, pi.Value) < 10 Then pi.Visible = False
Next
```

Comment: I found out your first code works wonders for the error popup but it didn't help filter the NA or (blank)


I get an error on your second code "Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method".

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Ralph! I adjusted the code to look like this and it got rid of the NA and blanks. If you have any other way to shorten this, I am sure to put that to the test :)

```
For Each pi In pf.PivotItems
   If IIf(VarType(pi.Value) = vbError, 0, pi.Value) < 10 Or _
   IIf(VarType(pi.Value) = vbError, 0, pi.Value) = "NA" Or _
   IIf(VarType(pi.Value) = vbError, 0, pi.Value) = "(blank)" _
   Then pi.Visible = False
Next
```